# Is there a definition of reduced $E_\infty$ ring?

Tags: higher-category-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry, higher-algebra, ring-spectra

[Edit: I have completely changed the question in response to the replies given]

I am curious if there is well defined notion of *reduced  $E_\infty$-ring*.

Let $CAlg$ denote the $\infty$-category of $E_\infty$-ring, $CAlg_1$, the one category of communicative rings.  I would like to define the analog for *reduced ring*.

One categorically,  $ CAlg_1^{red} \hookrightarrow CAlg_1$ admits a left adjoint $A \mapsto  A^{red}:=A /nil(A)$.

---

We can define $$CAlg^{red} \hookrightarrow CAlg$$ as the $\infty$-cat. of $E_\infty$-rings whose underling  ring is reduced.
Does there exist a left adjoint? As mentioned in comments by Marc, this is false.

---

**Question[Edit]:** What *should* be the notion of  $E_\infty$-ring? Harry in the comment says that this should be an ordinary reduced ring. I would appreciate if some explanation could make this precise.

Comment: A reduced connective $E_\infty$-ring should be a reduced ordinary ring, if you interpret the higher homotopy as higher-order nilpotents.

Comment: In addition, $CAlg^{red}$ is not closed under limits in $CAlg$. For example, any square-zero extension $R\oplus M$ can be obtained as a pullback of $R\to R\oplus\Sigma M\leftarrow R$.

Comment: What would you want a definition of reduced $E_{\infty}$ ring for?

Answer (score 9):

As Harry points out, the usual approach (For example in Lurie's SAG) is to think of the map $R\to \pi_0(R)$ for a connective $E_\infty$ ring as some kind of quotient by a nil-ideal. This is justified by the fact that $R = \operatorname{lim}_n \tau_{\leq n} R$ is a limit of square-zero extensions $\tau_{\leq n} R\to \tau_{\leq n-1} R$. So if you work with connective $E_\infty$ rings, I think the only reasonable thing is to say that reduced ones are concentrated in degree $0$, and the reduction of $R$ is given by the (ordinary) reduction of $\pi_0(R)$.

This of course breaks down when allowing nonconnective rings. I think in that case there is no reasonable concept of reducedness, but of course it depends a lot on what you want to achieve with such a notion.